# Why this code giving me error though everything seems right?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert

Here are my 3 Tables.

```
Service  (Serviceid,service_type,sname,ratings,address,due_date,company)
Hotel    (hotelid,address,ratings,hotel_name,cityid)
Insurance(insuranceid,company,due_date)
```

Whenever a insert is made in Hotel table, then its hotelanme, ratings, address, hotelid should be entered in Service table also.

```
INSERT INTO HOTEL VALUES(NEXTVAL('HOTELSQ'),'123,APPLE STREET',5.0,'GRAND BHAGVATI HOTEL',1003);
```

Here is my code of Trigger in postgres.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INSERTFORHOTEL()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SERVICE(SERVICEID,SNAME,SERVICE_TYPE,RATINGS,ADDRESS) VALUES (NEW.HOTELID,NEW.HOTEL_NAME,'HOTEL',NEW.RATINGS,NEW.ADDRESS);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER INSERTHOTEL BEFORE INSERT ON HOTEL
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE INSERTFORHOTEL();
```

The trigger is run successfully but when I insert the record like entered above,it gives following error.

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "service_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (serviceid)=(3524) already exists.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO SERVICE(SERVICEID,SNAME,SERVICE_TYPE,RATINGS,ADDRESS) VALUES (NEW.HOTELID,NEW.HOTEL_NAME,'HOTEL',NEW.RATINGS,NEW.ADDRESS)"
PL/pgSQL function insertforhotel() line 3 at SQL statement
SQL state: 23505
```

And record is not entered..

I have done the same thing for Insurance table. Adding a record in insurance table also inserts record in Service table, it's done successfully.
But hotel table is remaining..

Comment: maybe you **already** have an entry with serviceid=3524?

Comment: No, it says that it has entry, but Service table has entries with insurance ids, as whenever i add insurance record, it inserts in service table successfully, but hotel entry is not inserted in service table.

Comment: Saving an `hotelid` as a `serviceid` sounds wrong. Are you sure you don't want `serviceID` as a sequence, and each `service` row contains a not unique `hotelid` that is a foreign key to the `hotel` table? (i.e. it gives the ability to have more than 1 service per hotel)

Comment: ah, so you are using two sequences to feed one table, and now they have collided. You need to review your design

Comment: For me, Insurance is a service. Hotel is a service. So all insurance entries will be mapped in service table. so serviceid will be same as insurance id and hotel id

Comment: then you can't use a sequence for hotels and another one for insurance. You could use 1 serviceSequence to feed all tables (but again, it sounds wrong, even in plain language)

Comment: it looks like your database design is very poor , you can alter your primary key constraint of service table from one column(i.e. Serviceid) to three column i.e. Serviceid, service_type, sname

Comment: or you can declare separate column for primary key having serial type in service table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same trigger code for both, `hotel` and `insurance` then you might have a conflicting concept.

You are adding the `INSURANCE_ID` as `SERVICE_ID` as well as `HOTEL_ID` as `SERVICE_ID`. Both, `INSURANCE_ID` and `HOTEL_ID` are sequences. So if there is a new row 42 in the `insurance` table, you are adding the 42 as `SERVICE_ID` into the `service` table. But if you get a 42nd row into your `hotel` table, you are getting a problem because you are not able to add the 42 as `SERVICE_ID` into your table anymore. It already exists from your `insurance` input. This is a unique constraint violation.

You should better not copy your IDs as new `SERVICE_ID`. Create an own `SERVICE_ID` column (type `serial` - or in case of **Postgres 10** and higher [`GENERATED AS IDENTITY`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/)) and then you could take the other IDs as reference into a separate column without an unique constraint.